# My Delegated Tasks view not showing data for all

Tags: tasks, list-view

In our org, one user is not able to see the tasks under "My Delegated Tasks" list. Other users with same profile and having same permission sets are able to their delegated tasks. The delegated tasks of that user are showing up in developer console when I queried for them, logged in as admin. Any ideas as to what is causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the Roles. If a user delegates the task to users below his role, then only the tasks falls under delegated task list view.